# Will Audacious support the Sound Menu?

Tags: indicator, indicator-sound, audacious

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to integrate Audacious in the sound menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86669/how-to-integrate-audacious-in-the-sound-menu)

Is there any plug-ins already available? I couldn't find any