# How to integrate Audacious in the sound menu?

Tags: audacious, indicator-sound

I was wondering if you would know a way to *integrate audacious in the sound menu*, just like banshee. The plugin inside audacious to put a status icon doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Audacious 3.2](http://audacious-media-player.org/news/7-audacious-3-2-beta1-released) (currently in beta stage), that has the built-in support for the MPRIS 2 protocol needed for Sound Menu integration.

Answer (score 4):

<s>It will, but I don't know how many more months or years it will take.</s>

Audacious project lead said:

> I think we're just waiting for a volunteer to do it.

Right now, **IT DOES!** [Audacious 3.2](http://audacious-media-player.org/news/7-audacious-3-2-released) supports the Sound Menu.

[image: Screenshot of Audacious in the Sound Menu]

I contacted the developers on IRC in 2010, I reported the bug [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/681994) and [upstream](http://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/issues/14).

Finally, today's Git version features a basic MPRIS 2 plugin enabled by default that works with the Ubuntu Sound Menu: http://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/issues/14#note-7

Comment: [Audacious 3.2 released](http://audacious-media-player.org/news/7-audacious-3-2-released)

Comment: [Audacious 3.2 available in WebUpd8 PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/updates-audacious-32-gnome-pie-04.html)

Answer (score 2):

After looking around for a bit, I couldn't find any plugins for that functionality.

However, the sound indicator does let you change Audacious' volume! :D (not that exciting I know).

I would recommend getting in contact with the developers of Audacious and encouraging them to make it utilize the sound menu in Ubuntu.

http://audacious-media-player.org/developers

It's only a matter of time 'till it happens! :)

Comment: Developers can get automagic support for the sound menu by supporting the MPRIS2 standard: http://www.mpris.org/2.0/spec/

Comment: I'm horribly unfamiliar with software development, unfortunately.:(  So all they would have to do is integrate that software library(?) with Audacious and it would support the Sound Menu?

Answer (score 2):

I started writing the plugin.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/audacious-plugins/+bug/658001

It correctly registers Audacious in the sound menu but the playback control buttons still don't have any effect.

Comment: Nice man! please finish that plugin çç

Comment: A sound menu registration plugin like that was needed in Maverick but it isn't anymore. To work with the sound menu Audacious is needed to support the MPRIS 2 interface (it currently supports the older MPRIS 1), but unfortunately I am not able to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Audacious v3.2 beta from a PPA which works with sound menu integration out of the box.
http://ubuntucafe.blogspot.com/2012/01/install-audacious-32-beta-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.