# mp3 player recommendation

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3-player

I would like to have an mp3 player that only displays a menu in the bar on the top of the screen or / and notifications. I don't want any complex music management, playlists etc., but I want to be able to quickly see (without switching to another desktop or window) what track is being played and select a directory or a particular track. Is such a player available for Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04?

Comment: [Audacious](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86669/how-to-integrate-audacious-in-the-sound-menu) can do this - there may be others in [our list of players](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-players-are-there)

Answer (score -1):

Most music players for Ubuntu can be minimised to an indicator. I know [gmusicbrower](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gmusicbrowser/) is one that can.

Comment: Well, I downloaded and tried gmusicbrowser. I did not manage to add my music, to start music playback or to minimize to an indicator. But thanks anyways.