# Sometimes there's no indicator-sound playback menu for Audacious v3.3.2?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, indicator-sound, audacious

If I run Audacious via keyboard shortcut, there will be no indicator-sound playback menu for that app on my top panel, below the speaker icon. However, if I double-click the audio file (or if I click at "Audacious" right below the speaker icon from the top panel), the audio controls (previous, play, pause, next) will be visible there, as expected.

Here's the screenshot what's happening when I run Audacious via keyboard shortcut. There is no playback menu within the indicator-sound for Audacious.

[image: No playback menu for Audacious]

I guess it could be a bug. Is there a fix/workaround for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will Audacious support the Sound Menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5795/will-audacious-support-the-sound-menu)

Comment: The problem is that I COULD see the playback menu if I double-click the mp3 file: http://goo.gl/LCbM7 ... but not if I run Audacious by using my shortcut key. Anyway, this is NOT a duplicate of the bug you referred to, since Audacious supports the Sound menu since v3.2 and I use v3.3.2.

Comment: That's great information for you to put in the _question_ so that it's obvious that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: There - I rephrased the _question_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a bug and I reported it here, so you could track the status of it:

http://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/issues/222